# Android Webview - Programmatically change orientation for specific webpage without reloading

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview

I'm trying to see how to go about changing a webview on a certain page so if that page contains a video they can watch it in landscape mode. I would like it to not reload the webview but allow that page to rotate. How can that be done? Not sure how to even go about it.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this, but I think it should work as what you want.

1. change the orientation from your code when needed
2. as you dont want to interrupt the content so disable activity retstarrt on orientation change
3. to change orientation from code use

   `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)`

   `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);`
4. and to prevent your activity from restarting when orientation change use the following in your manifest

   `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"`

Comment: I did try this but it doesn't seem to change the orientation. Where do I use the setRequestedOrientation at? I tried it in OnPageStarted but it didn't seem to do anything

Comment: check this http://russenreaktor.wordpress.com/2010/01/03/solved-set-screen-orientation-programmatically/